# Are NixOS questions more suitable at SO or Unix StackExchange?

Tags: discussion

https://nixos.org/community/ says the NixOS community is active on StackOverflow.

Are NixOS questions about programming?

Are they more suitable at SO or Unix StackExchange? If latter,

- How can those policing at SO tolerate that?
- Could someone reach out to the NixOS community and the SO community to let them know that this site would be a more suitable choice? Thanks.

Comment: Note that _a lot of people out there_ seem to think that StackOverflow is the only StackExchange site. We even have users here on U&L that calls _this_ site "StackOverflow".  What I'm saying is that the text you point to may not actually have received much thought.  We cater for questions regarding the use and administration of _any_ Unix system (with the usual exceptions around the applications running on top of macOS and other Apple OSes, which the askdifferent site cares more about)

Comment: Note that this site, U&L, is not SO, and it is also not the NixOS community, so it seems as if asking _here_ about issues relating to SO and the NixOS community is not really reaching the right people.  If you want to know about the moderation policies of SO, ask at SO. If you want to change a web page authored by the NixOS people, reach them in a more direct manner.

Answer (score 2):

Whether a NixOS question is more suitable for StackOverflow or Unix & Linux depends on the question.

If it's unclear, a user should consult the help center pages for the sites to see whether their NixOS question is more suitable for one or the other.

The relevant help center pages are here:

- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (Unix & Linux)
- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (StackOverflow)